# Browser compatibility issue with chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

This jsp home page is working fine with Mozilla and IE 7 but not in chrome. None of the images are being picked. Please advice.

```
                    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <!-- Libraries to include jstl tags -->
                    <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
    <!-- Libraries to include jstl tags -->
                    <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
    <!-- Libraries to include jstl tags -->
                    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
                    <html>
                    <head>

                    <%
                    String ua=request.getHeader("User-Agent").toLowerCase();
                // condition used for mobile compatibility    
                if(ua.matches("(?i).*((android|bb\\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hipt)) //Many such conditions are checked but I removed them to make it simple
            {
                      response.sendRedirect("index?source=mobile");
                      return;
                    }
                    %>

                    <title>Arizona Health Sciences Library EBM Search Engine</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_index.css" > -- included css

                    </head>
                    <body>
        <!-- Images that are not getting loaded -->
        <a href="http://arizona.edu"><img src="images/ua_logo_white.png" height="80" /></a>
        <div class="floatright">
        <!-- Images that are not getting loaded -->
        <a href="http://ahsl.arizona.edu/home"><img src="images/AHSL.png" height="80" width="100" /></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Links to different search engines -->
        <h2><a href="search?module=2">General Medicine</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="search?module=1">Emergency Medicine</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="search?module=3">Medical Imaging</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="search?module=4">Pediatrics</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="search?module=5">Surgery / Critical Care</a></h2>
        <!-- Static texts hard coded - Need to be replaced -->

        <footer>
        All content ©2012 Arizona Board of Regents. All rights reserved.
        </footer>

        </body>
                    </html>
```

style_index.css - This is the CSS used for this page. I am not sure if changes has to be made for this style sheet.

```
body {
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

body {

    background: url('../images/bg_top_repeat_dark_blue.jpg') repeat-x #f3f3f3;

    }

image
{
    border-width: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    }

#logo {
    height: 397px;
    text-indent: -10000px;
    margin-bottom: -135px;
    }
#logo.blank {
    text-indent: 0;
    }


h1 {
    padding-top: 80px;
    color: #202080;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

h2 {
    color: #202080;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;   
    }

.floatright
{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 18px;
}   

form {
    background: url('../images/search_box.png') no-repeat;
    height: 47px;
    }

input {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
}

input.text {
    width: 670px;
    padding: 13px 0 13px 24px;
    color: #505050;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    }

input.submit {
    width: 104px;
    padding: 13px 0 13px 10px;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
.ui-grid-a .ui-block-a {
    width: 30%;
}

footer {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px 0 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked Chrome settings? Maybe a reset? Tried incognito? Any plugins running? (Your markup/css look fine). Is this in dev? Is the page accessible online?

Comment: I tried all those and it didnt work. I had to remove few class properties under div element and somehow managed to make them work.. thank you !

Answer (score 0):

when you are in chrome with your webpage opened juat press f12. a window will open. now in the right it there will be your css code displaying. check the code with red or yellow warning signs. these signs tell that the code is wrong or not required by chrome.